# Replacement for getExternalStoragePublicDirectory() API 21-30

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

My app's `minSdkVersion` is 21 and `targetSdkVersion` is 30. I need to save image to external storage (to Pictures folder)

So, here's `saveImage` function:

```
fun saveImage(context: Context) {
    val fileName = "${System.currentTimeMillis()}.png"
    val fileType = "image/png"
    val folder = "MyApp"
    val imageQuality = 100

    val write: (OutputStream) -> Boolean = { outputStream ->
        this.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, imageQuality, outputStream)
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, fileName)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, fileType)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "${Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES}/$folder")
        }

        context.contentResolver.let {
            it.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues)?.let { uri ->
                it.openOutputStream(uri)?.let(write)
            }
        }
    } else {
        val imagesDir = Environment
            .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
            .toString() + File.separator + folder
        val file = File(imagesDir)
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir()
        }
        val image = File(imagesDir, fileName)
        write(FileOutputStream(image))
    }
}
```

Also I have this permission in Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
```

This is working ok, but `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` is deprecated in API 29+.
Is there a way to get rid of this deprecated function? Right now I just suppress the warning, but it feels kinda bad.

Comment: If it works, and i know it works, you can use it and you are ready for Android 10/11. Now wait what things Android 12 will bring.

Comment: But i see... you are not using that function for Android 10/11. So then what is the problem?

Comment: For Android 11 you dont need to use the media store. You can just write your files in the public Pictures directory in the classic way. And for Android 10 too requesting legacy external storage in application tag of manifest file.

Comment: @blackapps my question is about `else` case (API 21-28). Because my `targetSdkVersion` is 30 function `getExternalStoragePublicDirectory` marked as deprecated. Is there a way to replace it with something or warning suppression is the only way?

Comment: Maybe if you surround it or put it in an  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) ( //block } ? I do not understand that it gives warnings as here it does not.

Comment: @blackapps Nope. Still deprecated.

Comment: if (!file.exists()) {
            if ( !file.mkdir()) return;
        }